# Can you "bump" a question?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I saw that recently marked "active" questions are way more likely to be read and answered. While digging into the old questions I saw a couple that are actually quite interesting and might deserve some renewed attention. Can I "bump" them?

I know that the voting system should send interesting questions on the top but sometimes very nice questions just go unnoticed and therefore non-voted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If questions are edited (text or tags) they will be bumped to the top of the activity queue, but this should only be done if the question needs editing or clarification.

Another option is to offer a bounty on the question. This will bump the question to the top of the activity queue, and it will also be included under the "Featured questions" tab (which currently only has a single question) and posted by the SE Twitter account.

Comment: When you add a bounty, the question is posted to the SE Twitter account which does bump it. You can see [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/28326/revisions) in the revisions a bounty counts as a unnumbered revision.

Comment: @dustin Didn't know this. Thanks! I'm adding it to the answer.

Comment: Bounty is definitely the way to go. Thanks